# How to get notified in c# Console Application when Changes occur in MySql Db

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

How can I get notified in a C#/.NET Application when any changes occur in a MySQL Database?
What are some ways to get notified?
What could be the best approach?
I have thought of a way to run a stored procedure continuously to get a value from db and then check from the last values, but is that way correct or should I take some other approach?

Comment: well no it doesn't. Because there is no solution written in this link. As this question was asked quite a long time ago. looking forward to anyone who has solved this problem recently with some better approach.

Comment: Actually it does. There's no such mechanism in MySQL. Other databases have it but MySQL doesn't. Beyond that the query is way too broad - there are several ways to implement change notifications depending on requirements. Do you want notifications as soon as a change is performed? On a schedule? Just inserts or updates as well? What about the load?

Comment: Polling is *very* expensive unless you take great care to eg only check for new incrementing ID values. Otherwise you end up locking entire tables and transferring a lot of data for no reason. Rewriting your application so it sends notifications when a change is made is another possibility. Or maybe you could write to a queue and have a worker listen to it, write the changes to the database then notify subscribers. Or you could have a trigger write to a "Changes" table and poll that

Comment: Yes. I do want notification when ever a record is inserted or updated. what do you mean by load?